# How do you serve static content and dynamic content from the same .NET app?

Tags: c#, .net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using the following website: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/serving-static-files

I want to be able to serve static files from:

https://my-app-location-123456.appspot.com/

And I want to also serve dynamic content from my c# code in other locations:

https://my-app-location-123456.appspot.com/ajaxaction?param1=value1 ...

The example here says to turn on static files like this:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

But now my `app.Run` command:

```
app.Run(async (context) => {
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(responseString);
});
```

Doesn't do anything, the only thing my app will do now is serve the static content.

Does anyone have an example of serving both static content and dynamic content from the same app engine application?

Comment: Hello Nicholas,

You may find a useful complete example that includes the "await context.Response.WriteAsync(responseString); " line in the "Quickstart for .NET in the App Engine Flexible Environment" [online document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart). 

It is recommendable to rather use Cloud Storage to host static assets for dynamic web apps. Benefits:

- Cloud Storage essentially works as a content delivery network. 

- Your app's load will be reduced.

- Bandwidth charges for accessing content can often be less with Cloud Storage.

Comment: yeah i know that. but i wanted to combine the two in this one situation. its sounding like it's not possible and that's fine.